# How to increase int value obtained from previous response

Tags: jmeter

I'm using jmeter and I would like to automate below scenario :
(In general I would like to increase value, I already know how to extract value from previous request)

1. Execute request_1
2. Extract value1 from request_1 using Regular expression extractor
3. Increment value1.
4. Put new value (increased) to the request_2

Any idea how can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum), you can sum an arbitrary number of arbitrary integers via it.

Given you have a JMeter Variable called `yourVar` where the extracted value lives, the relevant `__intSum()` function configuration to increment `${yourVar}` value by `1` will be something like:

```
${__intSum(${yourVar},1,yourVar)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Increment Variable]

If the value you're getting from the Regular Expression Extractor is more than `2 147 483 647` you will need to use [__longSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) instead.

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) guide for more information on JMeter functions concept.